# What's the upper bound of f(n) = n^4 + 100n^2 + 50?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I'm solving some exercises related to Big-O and I'm stuck on this one:

```
Exercise - Find upper bound for f(n) = n^4 + 100n^2 + 50
```

I tried to solve it step by step but something is wrong ...:

```
1.=> n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 <= O(g(n))
2.=> n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 <= Cn        ** Added -n^4 to both sides
3.=> n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 -n^4 <= Cn -n^4
4.=> 100n^2 + 50 <= Cn - n^4         ** Put n in common
5.=> 100n^2 + 50 <= n(C - n^3)       ** Divided n in the opposite site
6.=> (100n^2 + 50)/n <= C -n^3       ** Assumed 1 for n
7.=> 100 + 50 <= C - 1                      
8.=> 151 <= C
```

There is something wrong because the answer is c = 2 and n=11. I saw this very same question being asked on stackoverflow but without a step by step solution

Comment: What's "the" answer? Trivially n^4+100n^2+50 <= 151n^4 for n>=2, so an answer c=151, n=2. There's a solution for any c>1.

Comment: @Down Voter, please explain the reason for down-voting so that I can improve my question

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking why f(n) is O(n^4)? I guess you're trying to prove that f(n) <= Cn^4 for all n>N, but I don't understand what you're calculating in your 8 steps. Maybe your question is that you've calculated "C" and "N" and got a different "C" and "N" from some other answer? Perhaps your mistake is that you think these constants are unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite simple to guess that the Upper bound for this function would be O(n^4), because k * n^4 can overpower any multiple of n^3 and other multiples of n lower than 4, after a certain value of n (where k is a multiple).

Let's take a few sample example:

1. n^4 < 2*n^4, for all n>1.
2. n^4 + n^3 < 2*n^4, for all n>2.

In your case, you need to find the coefficient K which would satisfy your equation, such that n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 <= k * (n^4).

I'll leave the correct equation to be solved by you, as the one which you've shown is plainly incorrect:

```
n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 <= O(g(n))
n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 <= O(n^4)
n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 <= k * n^4
n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 <= n^4 + 100*n^4 + 50*n^4
n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 <= 151 * (n^4)
// O(n^4) achieved, for all n >= 1.
```

You can solve this equation by converting it into a quadratic equation by substituting n^2 by t, and then equation reduces to:

```
t^2 + 100t + 50 <= k * t^2
// left for you to solve this.
// check for what value of `k` and `t`, this equation gets satisfied.
```

Comment: Developing further `n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 <= k * n^4` I get: `n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 -n^4 <= k * n^4 - n^4 (added -n^4 in both sides)` and I get `=> 100n^2 + 50 <= k (cannot develop further...)`. In case of the second equation `=> t^2 + 100t + 50 <= k * t^2` I get `=> t^2 + 100t + 50 - t^2 <= k * t^2 - t^2` and finally `=> 100t + 50 <= k`. I'm still fighting to see c=2 and n=11 :-(

Comment: Ok If I pick the second equation `t^2 + 100t + 50 <= k * t^2`should I plug different values of t and k (by trial and error) until I find k=2 and n=11 ? This seems to be a lot of effort, is there some math to find theses values ?

Comment: @marcoshass - Hey! There doesn't exist a unique way of solving this equation. Your n and k will keep on varying dependently for different values of them. You should not at all be worried about that. It can be any value, ***you should only focus on the upper bound, i.e., the power of n*** - (n^4 here). Hence, the upper bound qualifies as O(n^4).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, we can solve this in a simple way :-

1. n^4+100*n^2+50 -- Lets reduce this equation to quadratic by assuming n^2 = t
2. t^2+ 100*t+50  -- equation changes as mentioned
3. Using Quadratic formula and Solving this equation ( t^2+100*t+50) we get two answers.
4. t = -100 +/- sqrt( 100^2 - 4*1*50)/2.1
5. t = -71.8 & -128.2 -- now substituting the values back to n^2
6. n^2 = -71.8 & -128.2
7. n = sqrt(-71.8) & sqrt(-128.2) = 8.47 & 11.32 -- looking at the upper bound numbers and trying to solve what could be the first biggest number to substitute for n.
8. n = 11
   Hence, we are taking n = 11 as the first biggest number that can be used for finding upper bound

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @Srini, could you please comment the results in step 5, -71.8 and -128.2 are the wrong result. The x1 and x2 values are -0.5 and -99.5 correspondently. I would appreciate any explanation from you, thx

Answer (score 0):

> n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 <= 2n^4 , for all n>=11.

Because, till 10, the n will have negative value.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for n0 is 11 because if we assume n value =11 and c value as 2 ,then the condition satisfies for the big oh notation which is f(n)<=O g(n), put n=11 and solve the quadratic equation u will get your answer try using it mathematically.
Thanks .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

We need to find, smallest rate of growth, g(n) such that

c g(n) >= f(n) for n>=k.

For some constant value of c and k, the above equation will hold true. We do not consider lower values of n. This means g(n) for low values of n is not important. For large values of n, g(n) will be the maximum rate of growth of f(n).

Here, f(n)= n^4 + 100 n^2 + 50

When n is very large, g(n) = n^4

Find c and k, so that c n^4 >= n^4 + 100 n ^2 + 50

If we discard, lower terms 100 n^2 and 50. we can say c should be 2.

2 n^4 >= n^4 .

To find value of k, try substituting n^2 = t, n^4 = t^2 and c=2,

2t^2 >= t^2 + 100t + 50

t^2 >= 100t +50

If i start putting values of t from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6, 7, 8, 9, and 10 and t^2 =100

At 10, i still have

100,00 <= 100, 00 +50

At t= 11, and t^2 = 121, i have below

14,641 >= 12150.

So my k will be 11.

Answer (score 0):

1)f(n)=n^4+100n^2+50

2)f(n)<=cg(n)

3)here clearly g(n)=n^4 neglecting the smaller terms

4)now if we consider f(n)<=2n^4(so c=2)

5)n^4+100n^2+50<=2n^4

6)n^4-100n^2>=50

7)n^2(n^2-100)>=50

8)as n must be a positive constant then n^2 >100

9)if we consider the next square number then n^2=121 and n=11 and previously shown c=2